# Listview with horizontal Listviews

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontallist

I want to make a ListView that contains items that has a Horizontal Listview. I have seen several apps doing this. Netflix does something simular, they use ViewPagers instead of ListViews. My problem is that my ListView lags alot,  espacially the first time that I scroll down the list. I am using the ViewHolder pattern and I also keep a HashMap with the adapters for the horizontal ListViews so that the adapters only needs to be created once. But it still lags. How can I make it more smooth?

Comment: Scollable view not contain Scrollable child.

Comment: it is possible. It works but lags alot